Self Hosted Owin Web API Injecting parent instance (Ninject)
I currently have a Windows service that creates a self hosted Owin web api.  From inside the controllers I access the parent class using a static reference to the class.
I have come to a situation where I need to have multiple instances of the parent class so my static referencing will no longer work.
From the research I have done, the best way forward is to use a DI framework such as Ninject to inject the parent class into the controller.
That way as each instance starts up their own Owin API, access to the instance is available inside the controller.
What I'm struggling with is the syntax to inject the instance of the parent class creating the Self Hosted API into the pipeline.
Has anyone done anything similar?  Or can point me in the right direction.
Thanks,
Danno.

I typically use Autofac as my IoC container of choice. They have some documentation and samples for OWIN here: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/owin.html
